# What is /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily

Tags: apt

This morning I went to install an app on one of my Ubuntu machines and found I was locked out by apt.system.daily. This is not in the root cron, so please tell me where it is running from?

```
root@acer:/home/stephen# apt install htop
 E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
 E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I found this interesting because I have purged update-manager. I like to take care of updates on my own. So then looking into it I find this :

```
root@acer:/home/stephen# ps -ef | grep apt
root     23463     1  0 06:23 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh 
/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
root     23468 23463  0 06:23 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh 
/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
```

Comment: Ah yes. So it is. Thank you.  I will stop it with sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer

Comment: I disabled these with ````systemctl disable apt-daily.timer```` and ````systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer````